# VC++ Equivalent for LLVM `copying member subobject of type 'std::atomic<int>' invokes deleted constructor`

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, clang

> Does anyone know if there is a VC++ flag number for the error produced by LLVM for a `copying member subobject of type 'std::atomic<int>' invokes deleted constructor`error?

This typically happens in cases like the ones reference in [this post](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/215095/visual-c-compiler-allows-use-of-deleted-copy-const.html) and expressions like `std::atomic<int> foo = -1`.

Comment: Write some code that does that and see what happens.

Comment: I am on VS 2017 and do not even get a warning when I program something like that. I could try an online compiler and just see if it give me other output.